# c# Core MVC user identity / how can I save last login (via cookie)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I use the user identity in ASP.NET Core MVC - this works perfectly, but I want to save the last login and a log if a user logs in via cookie ("remember me" function).

Where can I add my functionality?

Comment: check [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1800779.aspx?+how+can+i+do+Remember+me+on+login+section)

Comment: The post is unfortunately not for ASP.net Core and does not help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem.

I added in the user-model:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> UserDataLastLogin { get; set; }
```

and add in the login-function if login is successful:

```
user.UserDataLastLogin = DateTime.Now; _context.SaveChanges();  
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Loginsucess", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```